# How to extract SSL certificate properties

Tags: powershell, properties, ssl-certificate

I want a tool which can run on a server, that would extract and return specified properties from an already installed SSL certificate. I am specifically interested in the "issuer" and "thumbprint" properties. I know that I can simply open the certificate's properties dialog and copy these, and then paste them into my app, but to avoid a possibly error-prone manual process when others will be doing this at multiple sites, i would like a tool or script I can call that would simply return the value of a specified property from a specified certificate. I am fine if i need to make a separate call for each desired property. The more turnkey this is, the better. Are there any suggestions, please?

Comment: It's doable. Give it a go and ask if you have a _specific_ problem. Literally copied your question title with "PowerShell" added to Google; you shouldn't have to go further than the first couple of results.

Comment: This is now first result on google :D

Comment: @100r it ends up like that so many times. But people will still point you to a search engine instead of actually teaching you something or referring a reliable source that one can trust. Even though an OP asks a question that may be useful for others.

Answer (score 5):

You want to do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\ | Select Issuer,Thumbprint
```

Here is a list of properties you can easily get from **System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2** objects(common certificates).

```
Name                 MemberType     Definition                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
----                 ----------     ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Archived             Property       bool Archived {get;set;}                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Extensions           Property       System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ExtensionCollection Extensions {get;}                                                                                                                                      
FriendlyName         Property       string FriendlyName {get;set;}                                                                                                                                                                                               
Handle               Property       System.IntPtr Handle {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                  
HasPrivateKey        Property       bool HasPrivateKey {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Issuer               Property       string Issuer {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
IssuerName           Property       System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName IssuerName {get;}                                                                                                                                        
NotAfter             Property       datetime NotAfter {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                     
NotBefore            Property       datetime NotBefore {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PrivateKey           Property       System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm PrivateKey {get;set;}                                                                                                                                                       
PublicKey            Property       System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey PublicKey {get;}                                                                                                                                                     
RawData              Property       byte[] RawData {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
SerialNumber         Property       string SerialNumber {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                   
SignatureAlgorithm   Property       System.Security.Cryptography.Oid SignatureAlgorithm {get;}                                                                                                                                                                   
Subject              Property       string Subject {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
SubjectName          Property       System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName SubjectName {get;}                                                                                                                                       
Thumbprint           Property       string Thumbprint {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Version              Property       int Version {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
DnsNameList          ScriptProperty System.Object DnsNameList {get=,(new-object Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.DnsNameProperty -argumentlist $this).DnsNameList;;}                                                                                                
EnhancedKeyUsageList ScriptProperty System.Object EnhancedKeyUsageList {get=,(new-object Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.EnhancedKeyUsageProperty -argumentlist $this).EnhancedKeyUsageList;;}                                                                     
SendAsTrustedIssuer  ScriptProperty System.Object SendAsTrustedIssuer {get=[Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.SendAsTrustedIssuerProperty]::ReadSendAsTrustedIssuerProperty($this);set=$sendAsTrustedIssuer = $args[0]...
```

Comment: I will only mention that this is how you actually could get a list of properties to look up the ones you're searching for: "ls Cert:\LocalMachine\Root | Get-Member -MemberType Property,ScriptProperty".